# Istio retry not works

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

There are two service, ws001-api invokes ws002-pingpong via gRPC

```
######## ws001-api #########
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ws001-api
  labels:
    app: ws001-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ws001-api
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        auth-injection: enabled
        app: ws001-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ws001-api
          image: yw4code/ws001-api:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 7001
              protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ws001-api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: ws001-api
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7001
      targetPort: 7001

######## ws002-pingpong #########
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ws002-pingpong
  labels:
    app: ws002-pingpong
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ws002-pingpong
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ws002-pingpong
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ws002-pingpong
          image: yw4code/ws002-pingpong:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: grpc
              containerPort: 7002
              protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ws002-pingpong
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: ws002-pingpong
  ports:
    - name: grpc
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7002
      targetPort: 7002
---
```

And here is my retry definition

```
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: retry
spec:
  hosts:
    - ws002-pingpong
  http:
    - timeout: 3s
      route:
        - destination:
            host: ws002-pingpong
            port:
              number: 7002
      retries:
        attempts: 3
        perTryTimeout: 1s
        retryOn: unavailable,cancelled,deadline-exceeded,internal,resource-exhausted,connect-failure,gateway-error,refused-stream
```

I added an panic keep ws002-pinpong (container) getting crash, made k8s retry it

```
ReplicaSet "ws002-pingpong-d459bb59b" has timed out progressing.; Deployment does not have minimum availability.
```

istio-proxy in ws002-pingpong pod is alive. but didn't get any message.
ws001-api get following response via gRPC

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = no healthy upstream
```

But still can't get any metrics about retrying in prometheus.
metric envoy_cluster_upstream_rq_retry of the pod is zero. Can any one figure it out?

Comment: Hi, which errors are You receiving? Some of the errors do not trigger retry logic according to Envoy [docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/router_filter.html#x-envoy-retry-on).

Comment: Hi the error in ws001-api is
"Error #01: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = no healthy upstream"
I think it should be trigger if I specify - unavailable retryOn Option for gRPC
@PiotrMalec

Comment: After looking into it there have been several issues with retry feature in istio. Can You check if the simplest retry configuration works at all? For example from this [guide](https://istiobyexample.dev/retry/). Also which istio version do You use?

Comment: @areschan, did you figure out the root cause for this?